# Muhammad (saw) wanting to marry daughter of Abbas, is this hadith authentic?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, prophets

**Muhammad (saw) wanting to marry daughter of Ibn Abbas is this hadith authentic?**

Muhammad saw Um Habiba the daughter of Abbas while she was fatim (age of nursing) and he said, "If she grows up while I am still alive, I will marry her.

Musnad Ahmad, Number 25636

Comment: Abbas, not Ibn Abbas

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to this [Hadith](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=25638&bk_no=6&flag=1), which is quoted in [Musnad Ahmad (44/440, 26870 of al-Risala edition)](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/22545), [Musnad abi Ya'la (12/502, 7075)](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32852/7134) and [al-Kabeer (25/92, 238)](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1733/26320) of Imam at-Tabarni etc. the major problem here is the main route and known narrator of the sirah ibn Ishaq who is considered as not reliable in hadith matters, even [the son of Imam Ahmad said](https://al-maktaba.org/book/10906/4929) quoting his father: لم يكن يحتج به في السنن No body used his narration (alone) when it comes to sunnah/hadith as an evidence.

In fact hadith scholars tend to say the hadith is **da'if** because hadith of ibn Ishaaq isn't reliable if there's no similar narration of any other narrator on the matter, which is the case here all the scholars who compiled this hadith have (only) ibn Ishaaq in the narrator chain.

Another narrator who is [not reliable in the chain is Hussayn ibn Abdullah ibn Obaydallah ibn 'Abas](https://al-maktaba.org/book/12579/1217) حسين بن عبد الله بن عبيد الله بن العباس : he was a known narrator of manakeer.

Two major scholars have qualified this hadith as dai'f: Sheikh Shoayb al-Arnaout in [his examination of Musnad Ahmad](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/22545) and Sheikh Hussayn Salem Assad in [his examination of Musnad abi Ya'la](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32852/7134). (See also this [thread](http://www.hurras.org/vb/showthread.php?t=41006) in Arabic on the matter)

An other note on the hadith matn, assuming it would be accepted: The Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) only said that he would marry her if.... if she reached the right age for marriage, so this doesn't have nothing to do with desire, but could be related to strengthen the relationship to al-Abbas as he did with Abu Bakr and Omar (May Allah be pleased with them). So this hadith shows the position of al-'Abbas and his ranking by the Messenger of Allah.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: Please report the comment below that insults our beloved Prophet (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam).

Comment: @Medi1Saif , I think there are some problems with the translation given for لم يكن يحتج به في السن . I'm not sure and I'm not good at Arabic. But, if I'm not mistaken, [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/148009) translated the same words as "He did not quote it as evidence with regard to issues having to do with the Sunnah of P...". It's not the same as the given one in your answer. However there are similar words from Ahmad, "لَيْسَ هُوَ بِحُجَّةٍ" and IslamQA (Ibid) translated it as "He (Ibn Ishaq) cannot be quoted as evidence". I hope you will pay some attentions to this issue.

Comment: @RafidAbrar I've added an explanation.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Yes, but I'm talking about the translation. Your given translation says "No one" whereas a translation given by IslamQA says "He" referring to Ahmad, if I'm not mistaken. But there is a similar quotation from Ahmad "لَيْسَ هُوَ بِحُجَّةٍ" which has been translated as "He (Ibn Ishaq) cannot be quoted as evidence" which is very similar to your given translation. I hope it's clear.

Comment: @Medi1Saif The [translation they gave](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/148009): ‘Abu’l-‘Abbaas ibn ‘Uqdah said: I heard ‘Abdullah ibn Ahmad ibn Hanbal say: My father used to seek out the hadith of Ibn Ishaaq and write it down and narrate it in the Musnad. It was said to him: Did he quote it as evidence? He said: ***He did not quote it as evidence with regard to issues having to do with the Sunnah of the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him)***." If you see the Arabic version, the last part is: لم يكن يحتج به في السنن **which is the part you quoted**.

Comment: @Medi1Saif There is another quotation from Ahmad: ليس هو بحجة [which is translated](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/148009) as: "***He (Ibn Ishaq) cannot be quoted as evidence***". This is very similar to your given translation

Comment: @Medi1Saif, I think it can be better if you give, ".....even **Imam Ahmad said: ليس هو بحجة He (alone) cannot be quoted as evidence (when it comes to sunnah/hadith)**" with or without any modification. And Allah knows best. Jazzak Allah Khair.